# I am trying to learn ajax within wordpress to delete a table entry but am getting confused on placement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have created a wordpress addon to add fixtures and results for sports team within different leagues, you can view fixtures and results for each league and delete/edit them as needed.

I have added a button at the end named Delete, and when I click that button I would like it to delete the entry from the table and make the whole entry disappear with a fade.

I have been looking up websites on how ajax works with wordpress but am getting confused.

This is my button code and javascript on the fixtures_admin.php page within my plugin.

```
<input type="button" id="<?php echo $elementid; ?>" class="submitDeleteEntry" name="submitDeleteEntry" value="Delete" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.submitDeleteEntry', function () {
        var id = this.id;
        //alert(id);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {"action": "fws_delete_row", "id": id},
            success: function (data) {
               
            }
        });
     });
</script>
```

The $elementid is just using the variable id from the database and works as intended.

If I uncomment the alert(id); line I do get an alert with the id.

I have placed this code at the top of the page registering the ajax

```
function fws_delete_row(){
    global $wpdb;
    $dbtable = $wpdb->prefix . 'fws_fixtures';
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $wpdb->delete($table, array('id' => $id));    
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_fws_delete_row', 'fws_delete_row' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_fws_delete_row', 'fws_delete_row' );
```

But when I click the delete button nothing happens. I have tried looking around the internet for examples of how to do it but can't seem to find the way to do it.

I am happy to come to the conclusion myself but if someone could please explain to me where I am going wrong I would really like to learn.

I know once the delete happens from the database I will need to add more code in for the line to be deleted on the page but for now I just want to get the button at least deleting.

I thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You created a variable called `$dbtable`, then below you're trying to use `$table`. That's why it doesn't work :P Also, it might be a good idea to develop your plugin with `WP_DEBUG` set to `true` so you can spot these errors more easily. See [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) for more details.

Comment: @cabrerahector it actually doesnt matter because $dbtable and $table are the same variable within the same page.

Comment: Alright, if you say so. I'd still enable the debug log as suggested if I were you.

Comment: @cabrerahector I have debugging mode on and when i press the delete button I get no debugging errors. The only debugging error I get is an undefined index: submitDeleteEntry which i originally used to delete entries until I got over 1000 fixtures its getting time consuming keep reloading the page and having to move back down to where I was.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out where I was going wrong, I just had the javascript at the bottom of the file, I had not registered it correctly as indicated in this page https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

I needed to load it into the admin_footer using the code below

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'fws_delete_javascript' );
function fws_delete_javascript() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
                            jQuery(document).on('click', '.submitDeleteEntry', function () {
                                var id = this.id;
                                //alert(id);
                                jQuery.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: ajaxurl,
                                    data: {"action": "fws_delete_row", "id": id},
                                    success: function (data) {
                   
                                    }
                                });
                            });
</script>
<?
}
```